# Django throws exception: ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: python, django

I´m working with Django Framework and it throws this exception: ModelForm has no model class specified.

This is my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from DjangoApp1.forms import login_form
from django.shortcuts import render  #For render templates

def login_view(request):    

    form = login_form()
    context = { 'form': form, 'mensaje':'Logeandose'}

    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = login_form(request.POST)     
        usuario = request.POST.get('username')
        contrase = request.POST.get('password')
    # Hacer el login
        user = authenticate(username=usuario, password=contrase)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            context['mensaje'] =  u'Logeado como  %s, contraseña %s' % (usuario, contrase)
        else:
            context['mensaje'] =  u'No usuario  o contraseña incorrecta'

    return render (request, 'DjangoApp1/login.html', context)
```

And the models.py where I´ve the login form:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class login_form(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.SlugField (max_length=8, 
                             label='Usuario: ')
    password = forms.SlugField (max_length=8, 
                        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),  
                        label='Contraseña:',
                        help_text='Hasta 8 letras')

class Meta:
    model  = User
    fields = ('username',  'password')
```

Comment: Is your `class Meta` indentation like that? If so, then you need to make it indent one more level because `class Meta` belongs to form class.

Comment: Also, python classes should use camelcase, variable names should be all lower case with underscores, so your form should be `LoginForm`. Look at pep8 definition: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: If I write Meta class into LoginForm class it throws an exception of indentationError

Comment: Then your indentation is not correct, maybe you mixed tab with spaces. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Thanks to both of you! The problem was solved.

Comment: Glad it helped. But I thought I'm the only one leaving the comment here. Where's the other guy? :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to indent your `class Meta` because it's part of the model form class definition:

```
class login_form(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.SlugField (max_length=8, 
                             label='Usuario: ')
    password = forms.SlugField (max_length=8, 
                        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),  
                        label='Contraseña:',
                        help_text='Hasta 8 letras')
    class Meta:
        model  = User
        fields = ('username',  'password')
```

[Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) explains this in details.